# std::atexit() doesn't work if std::cin has been used in the code

Tags: c++, windows

Couple days ago it was that I've started working with C++, so quite an amateur and stupid question probably:

Function provided in std::atexit() gets called when my application closes. Very happy. But as soon as I have used std::cin to get input from the user side (at least once), that function doesn't get called.

This is a console application.

Edit: I would like to still execute my void Close() function whilst the program is waiting for input. But I can only achieve that if my program is not waiting for input. I reckon this might not be the correct way of doing this, my program starts Apache web server and Mysql database server (with ShellExecuteEx()) and when my application stops I'm stopping them as well.

I have tried std::set_terminate() as well.

```
// This is super good, everything works as expected

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Close()
{
    // Code I need to run when program closes.
}

int main()
{
    std::atexit(Close);

    // Some code...

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I wait for a user input, 'void Close()' won't be called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Close()
{
    // Code I need to run when program closes.
}

int main()
{
    std::atexit(Close);

    std::string example;
    std::cin >> example;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a new C++ user you probably don't need `std::atexit`. It is a very special function usable only in specific rare circumstances.

Comment: My program starts Apache web server and Mysql when running. When my program closes, I stop those processes. Which works fine. Would you say, that there is another way I should use to stop those processes? (I forgot to add windows tag)

Comment: One way is to never call `exit` from any function, but always make sure there's a return path to the `main` function, even if it has to be through (caught) exceptions. Then just "clean up" before leaving the `main` function.

Comment: Well, it could be a bit premature to try and manipulate external processes and stuff while you are still not 100% sure how standard input works. But this is just my opinion of course.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Well, I just made an application for myself that configures and launches Apache and Mysql, then configures PHP for me. Everything works pretty good, but I had the idea to implement some command line interpretation too, which I have successfully made as well. Well you know what, everything works, just my application goes to background instead of actually stopping if I use std::cin. And I just can't find out why.

Comment: "wait for input" is the problem.  Your program is buried deep inside an OS call and not executing any code.  If you don't type Ctrl+Z but click the console's Close button then the OS must step in and terminate the program forcibly.  So don't pass Go and don't collect 200 bucks.  Detecting the console closing requires using SetConsoleCtrlHandler().

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I wait for a user input, `void Close()` won't be called.

Indeed, but that's desired. When waiting for user input, your program is not yet about to shut down. As soon as the user does give an input that will be parsed into the `example` string object, it is - and *this* is when `Close()` is being called. Hence, when executing, type some characters, hit enter, this triggers `Close()`.

Comment: I see, thank you. So you say I cannot trigger some kind of "exit function execution" whilst my program is waiting for input? I start some Windows processes in my program that I would need to stop when my program closes.

Comment: Not sure if I get that, but generally no, when a function is waiting for input, you can't simply stop it from doing so, externally. If you have to handle multiple subprocesses, consider using a library for that purpose, I think Boost has something that could help.